# Hibernate, mysql and Tomee - org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found

Tags: hibernate, jpa

The proyect compiles but when I try:

```
SupplierEntity entity = em.find(SupplierEntity.class, 1);
```

Or I try:

```
Query query = em.createNamedQuery("SupplierEntity.loadAll");
List<SupplierEntity> entityList =  query.getResultList();
```

Returns the error:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare
>   statement

UPDATE:

The root exception is:

> Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object
>   not found: SUPPLIERINFO

I tried to remove the pool (resource) from the server.xml and the proyect not fails so I think my problem is related with the configuration.

---

I searched other similar posts and I think my code is fine. Any idea?

I'm using Tomee as server.

Entity:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "SupplierInfo")
@javax.persistence.NamedQueries({

    // Loading list Of Suppliers
    @javax.persistence.NamedQuery(name = "SupplierEntity.loadAll", query = "SELECT supplier FROM SupplierEntity AS supplier"),

})
public class SupplierEntity implements Serializable, Comparable<SupplierEntity>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7847645372201362008L;

    // ----------- Attribute Definitions ------------
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="supplierId", unique=true, insertable=true, updatable=true, nullable=false)
    private Long supplierId;

    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "supplierCode",  unique = false, nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length =20)
    private String supplierCode;

    @javax.persistence.Column(name = "supplierName",  unique = false, nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length =80)
    private String supplierName;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

Table in database:

```
CREATE TABLE `SupplierInfo` (
  `supplierId` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `supplierCode` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `supplierName` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`nirvanaId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Service:

```
@Stateless
public class SupplierService implements Serializable{

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "myapp.supplier")
EntityManager em;

    public int test(){
   ...
   ...
        //SupplierEntity entity = em.find(SupplierEntity.class, 5);
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery("SupplierEntity.loadAll");

        List<SupplierEntity> entityList =  query.getResultList();

     //catch javax.persistence.NoResultException ex
     //catch Exception ex --> the exception entry into here.
    }
```

Persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="myapp.supplier" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:openejb/Resource/supplierPool</jta-data-source>
    <!--SUPPLIER -->
    <class>com.myapp.entity.SupplierEntity</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="25"/>
        <property name="tomee.jpa.factory.lazy" value="true" />
        <!-- <property name="tomee.jpa.cdi" value="false" /> -->
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Server.xml of Tomee:

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" initialSize="34" maxActive="377" maxIdle="233"  minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="55000" minIdle="89" name="jdbc/supplierPool" password="pass" removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="55" testOnBorrow="true" timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="34000" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:3306/myapp_db" username="user" validationInterval="34000" validationQuery="SELECT 1"/>
```

Comment: No transaction associated with current thread - this error can happens if you don't have @Transactional on your service or method

Comment: Thanks, I added @ Stateless (I think @ Transactional is not necessary in this case) but now I have always the error "could not prepare statement". I edited my post and the title.

Comment: The answer is in the root cause of the stack trace. Did you read it?

Comment: `"SELECT supplier FROM SupplierEntity AS supplier"`, you don't have a `suplier` column in your table.

Comment: @BalusC the root cause is: "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: SUPPLIERINFO" but I already have a table "SupplierInfo"

Comment: your table name is in which case? it is looking for uppercase. so look in the JPA provider log for the actual SQL invoked ... aka debugging

Comment: @Neil Stockton I created other table with SUPPLIER_INFO and I made the changes in the code but the same error. On the other hand, I updated my post, I think the problem is related with the configuration.

Comment: It is asking about `SUPPLIERINFO` not `SUPPLIER_INFO`. As I already said, look at the SQL invoked for the query

Comment: @Neil Stockton I meant that I created other table with the name SUPPLIER_INFO and I made the changes on code @javax.persistence.Table(name = "SUPPLIER_INFO") but happens the same as with my first table "SupplierInfo". I think the problem is related with my configuration between Tomee and the persistence.xml file because I tried to remove the configuration from the server.xml and the proyect doesn't fail when it runs (only I try to retrieve info from the database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally my problem was solved including a file resources.xml in WEB-INF

```
<resources>
    <Resource id="nirvanaDatasource" type="DataSource">
        JdbcDriver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        JdbcUrl jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:3306/myapp
        UserName username
        Password password
    </Resource>
</resources>
```

I don't undestand why this file is necessary because I already included the pool and credentials in the server.xml of Tomee.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your query

```
@NamedQuery(name = "SupplierEntity.loadAll", query = "SELECT supplier FROM SupplierEntity supplier")
```

`AS` keyword is redundant and, I think, wrong

Comment: I think it's not wrong. My query is telling "get the complete object from the table SupplierEntity as supplier". If I wanted only one field, I can do " SELECT supplier.supplierName FROM SupplierEntity as supplier".

However I tried your solution but not work

Comment: `AS` keyword is present in the JPA spec and any decent JPQL docs, and is easily checked. Nothing to do with a query complaining about the table name

Answer (score 0):

The Exception is `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException` from which we can understand that the error come from your SQL query.

When we take a look at your SQL query:

```
"SELECT supplier FROM SupplierEntity AS supplier"
```

We can either understand that you are referring to a column `supplier` that doesn't exist in your table or you are trying to alias your table `supplierEntity` as `supplier`.

If you are aliasing the `supplierEntity` you should remove the `AS` keyword so just use:

```
"SELECT supplier FROM SupplierEntity supplier"
```

Or you can just write:

```
query = "from SupplierEntity supplier"
```

Comment: as I told @Nikolay Yashchenko, I tried without AS but I think that is not the problem. Maybe it's related with the root cause: "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: SUPPLIERINFO". But I already have a table "SupplierInfo"

Comment: Also I have the same issue with the em.find()

Comment: If you have the same issue with em.find() I think it means that your DB really doesn't have a table with name "supplierinfo".